Can my boss monitor my cellphone messages
I use my personal cellphone to access workplace emails when out of office; Rumors are that C-Suite monitors my personal text messages, Inbox messages, private email account.
Can I be disciplined for private comments on my cellphone?

Stop using your personal phone for work. You should ask for a work phone even better outside of the office you should stop working

Your boss doesn't have the technology to monitor your personal cellphone or private email account without your permission. --- The only way your boss knows about your private comments is from the people whom you send text messages to. Maybe, the receivers of your text messages want to earn some favors from the boss. So, they privately tell the boss about your text messages.

How can they do so?  If you text your non work friend and do not sign into the work wifi, how can they discover the contents of the text?


Rumors that C-Suite monitors my personal text messages, Inbox messages, private email account.

Highly unlikely. In most legislations that would be illegal especially without your explicit consent. It would require installing some monitoring software on your phone.

Can i be disciplined for private comments on my cellphone?

That depends on

Local laws (which vary GREATLY around the world)
Company policies
The details of your contract
The means by which the company gained knowledge about your comment and whether that was in full compliance with bullets 1, 2, and 3


Or it would require installing a pirate cell tower with monitoring. Which is possible; some police departments have done do with a court's permission... But which, again, is otherwise illegal in most advanced countries. If you are worried, wait until you are off site to use the phone gur anything embarrassing. Or just don't use the phone for anything embarrassing.

Enterprise mode does mean that your phone gets managed by the company. Most people don't read so they just click those "yes" buttons, but that's exactly what "Enterprise mode" does to your phone... it is like giving your house keys to your boss.

So - as per the comments - if this is even a potential issue or concern - the simple solution is to stop using your personal cell phone for accessing work emails.
If work has an issue with this - ask that they provide you with a company phone for monitoring work emails when out of office.
Now - I cannot speak to the rumors without more detail - however, if you have configured your phone with Exchange ActiveSync (which is pretty common) there is a warning message that pops up: Some info here and some of the policy wording makes it sound like Corporate can access your phone.
Even if your company enforces something like InTune mobile management: Text Messages are never collected.
However - if you have spicy comments or emails in your work email account - those are absolutely fair game.
From a legal point of view (IANAL) Hilmar mentioned about consent - and almost all of those monitoring type software do have consent pop-ups - which (if the tools have this capability) you would have agreed to on install or configuration.
Even then though, there is a legal minefield that they would have to negotiate.
Now I am going to do the equivalent of a Frame Challenge
I have a personal phone, I use it to access work emails, I have some content on my personal phone that is not work safe - yet I have no worries about the C-Suite, despite the fact I am an outspoken employee.
My point is: This concern is, IMO, tangential or secondary to some underlying issues between yourself and your management. In short - the Phone is not the problem, it is a symptom of the problem - and you might have better luck addressing the actual problem.
